# C OpenSSL login to POP Mail Server

Tags: c, email, openssl, client, pop3

I want to write a mail client in C. I use openssl, but I have a problem that when I use the command like "USER example" that work with telnet I always get a "unknown command" back.

The needed code is:

```
int login(BIO *bio) {
unsigned char buf_print[4096]; //Used for WebPrintLine to 
unsigned char user_log[] = {"USER me\n"};

if( WebSendLine(bio, user_log, strlen(user_log)) != 0) {
    printf("Couldn't login.\n");
    return -1;
}
WebPrintReturnLine(bio, buf_print, sizeof(buf_print));//Print the line to the display
}
```

And:

```
//Send one line of data
int WebSendLine(BIO *bio, unsigned char buf_write[], int strlenbuf) {
/*
BIO_write will attempt to write bytes to the socket. It returns the number of bytes actually written, or 0 or -1. As with BIO_read, 0 or    -1 does not necessarily indicate an error. BIO_should_retry is the way to find out. If the write operation is to be retried, it must be         with the exact same parameters as before. 
*/
if( BIO_write(bio, buf_write, strlenbuf) <= 0 ) {
    if( ! BIO_should_retry(bio) )
        return -1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

I am more or less a newbie, so I may have not understand yet how it really works, anyways.
My question ist what do I have to do so I do not get "unkown commad" back from the server?

I am looking forward to hear from you.

King regards,
Greenality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server expects a carriage return and line feed.  You should send "USER example\r\n"